# Case insensitive primary key realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have an object with the following structure:

```
class REObject:Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var status = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
    }
}
```

The flow is: I get an array of items from the BE, the user can enter the object's id and change the status. 
And the question is: how could get the item with case-insensitive id?

```
if let item = realm.object(ofType: REObject.self, forPrimaryKey: id) {
    return item
}
```

Comment: have you done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [isSameObjectAs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/c:@M@RealmSwift@objc(cs)RealmSwiftObject(im)isSameObjectAs:) in your class and compare lowercase (or uppercase) versions of `id` there

Comment: Can you kindly provide a code sample to illustrate a case-insensitive id?